# Android: Get the TextView from Custom Adapter in Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a custom adapter to fill my listview. In my adapter is a DataObjectHolder. This contain the views:

```
public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView label;
        public TextView dateTime, textViewIsAbonned, textViewAbos, textViewUserName;
        ImageView imageViewCardSmall;
        private GridView gridView;
        private GridViewAdapter gridAdapter;

        public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            label = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOther);
            dateTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewBig);
            textViewIsAbonned = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewIsAbonned);
            textViewAbos = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAbos);
            imageViewCardSmall = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewCardSmall);
            textViewUserName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUserName);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Adding Listener");
            gridView = (GridView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        }


    }
```

Now, I want to change the text from the textViewIsAbonned in my Activity, but I can't find a solution. Furthermore I use Fragments in my Activity. I call the Adapter in my Fragment in the post-Execute method from asyn-task:

```
    private class GetCustomerDetailsURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.e("IDRecyclerViewFragment ", "GET CUSTOMERDEITAILS URL");
//            progressBarProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//            getData();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            Log.e("IDRecyclerViewFragment", "TAB3");
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            if (!isCancelled()) {
                Log.e("IDRecyclerViewFragment", "TAB3");
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(StaticVariables.url_customer_details + CodesForURL.getCustomerDetailsOne + CodesForURL.getCustomerDetailsTwo +
                            CodesForURL.getCustomerDetailsThree + CodesForURL.getCustomerDetailsFour + "&uid=" + idOfUser); //idOfUser);
                    Log.e("IDRecyclerViewFragment", "for customer details is " + url.toString());
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    con.setUseCaches(true);
                    String readStream = readStream(con.getInputStream());

                    System.out.println(readStream);

                    arr = new JSONArray(readStream);
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                        object = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                    }
                    return readStream;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("IDRecyclerViewFragment", "TAB3");
                return null;
            }
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String string) {

            try {


                JSONObject customer = arr.getJSONObject(0);

                strUserName = customer.getString("name");
                strFullName = customer.getString("full_name");
                strAge = customer.getString("age");
                strEmail = customer.getString("email");
                strAbout = customer.getString("about_the_customer");
                strAboCounts = customer.getString("a");

                imageName = customer.getString("imageName");


                urlForImage = StaticVariables.baseUrlForImage + customer.get("imageName");
//                new DownloadImageTask(picture).execute(urlForImage);

//                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(urlForImage, picture, optionsFeedImage, null);
//                imageLoader.get(urlForImage, new com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
//                            @Override
//                            public void onResponse(com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageContainer imageContainer, boolean b) {
//                                logo_white.setImageBitmap(imageContainer.getBitmap());
//                            }
//
//                            @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
//                            @Override
//                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
//                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Profile Image for you!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
//                            }
//                        }
//                );
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                return;
            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                Toast.makeText(NewMainActivity.getContextOfApplication(), "can't get details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            mAdapter = new RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter(new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(getDataSet(), getActivity()));
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
//            progressBarProfile.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

And in my Activity, I call the Fragment for my MaterialViewPager:

```
mViewPager.getViewPager().setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                switch (position % 2) {
                    case 0:
                        return RecyclerViewFragment.newInstance();
//                    case 1:
//                        return WebViewFragment.newInstance();
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 1;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                switch (position % 4) {
                    case 0:
                        return "User Details";
                }
                return "";
            }
        });
```

To sum up, I want to change the text from the textViewIsAbonned from my Activity. How can I manage this?

Comment: Do you have only one item in the Adapter?

Comment: it is not the full adapter..

Comment: Thus you have a list of items and want to change a particular item from Activity? You can just implement any public method for your Fragment and get an instance in Activity to use this method. It is important to understand, that item's view should not be independent from item. If you want to change a text of TextView for separate item in the adapter, you have to **change item** and then **call** `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your model, then your adapter will update the view.

Don't forget to call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` so that your adapter knows that the model changed.

Comment: @fabiruu111 call it after you set the adapter, not before

Comment: also what is `getDataSet()` doing

Comment: getDataSet contain the list with data. You don't understand, I want to use the textview from the adapter in my activity to change its text.